# Puppeteer screenshot stop in random URL

Tags: node.js, typescript, screenshot, puppeteer

I have a service nodejs working in Ubuntu, using puppeteer to take screenshots of pages, but in some pages the method `page.screenshot({fullPage: true, type: 'jpeg'})` doesn't works in some random URLs and no errors are displayed in the log. The code is:

```
async takeScreenshot() {  
        console.log('trying take Screenshot [...]');
        let image = await this.page.screenshot({fullPage: true, type: 'jpeg'});
        console.log('Completed!');
        return image;
    }
```

An example of page that I had this problem is: https://nuevo.jumbo.cl/mayonesa-hellmanns-751-g-supreme-light/p

Comment: How did it not work for you?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are not waiting until the page is fully loaded before you take the screenshot. You need 'waitUntil':

```
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(inputImgUrl, {waitUntil: 'networkidle'});
```

So the whole thing should look like something like this:

```
(async() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(inputImgUrl, {waitUntil: 'networkidle'});
    await page.setViewport(viewPortData);
    await page.screenshot({path: outputFile, type: 'jpeg', quality: 50, clip: cropData});

    await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: This is my code that go to the page: async navigateTo(url) {
        if (!url)
          throw new Error('Missing URL');
        return await this.page.goto(url, {
            waitUntil: 'networkidle',
            networkIdleTimeout : 3000,
            timeout: 60000
        });
    }

Answer (score 0):

You did not explain how it did not work, or how you expected it to show, but I'm assuming it captured something like the following image.

[image]

When you first load the page, it'll load something like this, which is not related to puppeteer, since you are not telling the code to wait for certain amount, if you are doing so, I don't see it specified anywhere.

For me, just normal screenshot worked, except the region settings. I used version 0.13 and the following code,

```
await page.goto("https://nuevo.jumbo.cl/mayonesa-hellmanns-751-g-supreme-light/p", {waitUntil: "networkidle0"});
    await page.screenshot({
        path: "test_google.png",
        fullPage: true
    });
});
```

Comment: Before this code example, I set region cookies using JS. So I do not open this page.

Comment: Still you did not share more code (like you are saying you used cookies with JS), or you did not share the actual problem, or what you are expecting.